# Checking that float modulo int is finite ordinal

Tags: python, floating-point, modulo

In a for-loop, I'm integrating with respect to time with constant, fractional time step, `dt.` I only want to save the simulation results for integral (finite ordinal) time points. My solution is as follows,

```
dt = 0.1
steps = 100

for step in range(steps):
    if (step*dt) % 1 == 0.0:
        print step
```

I've never really trusted modular arithmetic on floats. Is there a better way to check if a float is integral or am I simply being paranoid?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is dangerous, in any programming language.  <s>In your example, `0.1` cannot be represented exactly by in floating-point, so that test will never pass (well I suppose it may do after 2^24 iterations or so)</s>.  In many cases, the step size may not have an exact representation in floating-point, so that the accumulated rounding error causes the test to erroneously trigger/not trigger.  In other cases, as the accumulated value gets larger, eventually it will begin to lose precision due to the increasing exponent (in your example, assuming Python uses single-precision by default, you'll get an erroneous trigger after 20971529 iterations).

Try to find a way to avoid performing equality tests on floating-point values (checking for integral values is one such test).  So in your case, just test on `step % 10`.

Comment: Is 2^24 just pulled out of nowhere, or does it have any meaning?

Comment: Doing any operation on a IEEE floating point is bound to give you errors, even if it is step%10.

Comment: @Dhaivat: A single-precision float has 23 mantissa bits (+1 implied), so after approximately that number of iterations, the OP's `step*dt` will have no fractional component (assuming Python uses single-precision by default).  As you may have guessed, I don't know Python at all; will `step` be an integer type or a floating-point type here?

Comment: @Dhaivat: Even if `step` is floating-point, so long as `steps` is less than 2^24, this should work fine.

Comment: `step` will be an `int.` I agree that explicitly testing `step % 10` is probably the best. However, this introduces the problem that you have to remember to change an extra parameter if you change your time step. This could be missed in large projects, or maybe that's just the paranoia again :)

Comment: "0.1 cannot be represented exactly [] in floating-point" is true, but "so that test will never pass" doesn't follow.  Try it and see.

Comment: @lafrasu: Indeed.  So it would be best to have a single parameter, which is used for both the control logic, and for deriving `dt`.

Answer (score 1):

I don't trust floats either, you can use [the Decimal type](http://docs.python.org/library/decimal.html) or, you can use [types](http://docs.python.org/library/types.html). I like types better.